# Different /ch/ Sounds

Tags: pronunciation

I might be hearing it wrongly, but I’ve noticed there are actually more than two types of *ch* sounds:

- strong (like in Hebrew), e.g. in *nach* or *Woche*
- weak, e.g. in *ich*
- /x/ or /k/, e.g. in *nächste*
- like in the English word *Charlie* (?), e.g. in *Mädchen,* at least when spoken at normal speed (this one got me really confused)
- a (weak) /ch/ sound (not a *ch*), e.g. in almost any word ending on *g* like *vierzig.*

Can someone please clarify? Which ones are indeed correct? Are there unofficial rules (such as: after /d/ it always sounds like /k/). Historically, was there a different writing for each?

I am primarily interested in standard German.

Comment: well, i'm not an expert but at the ch-sounds there are also regional differences! -- for example **Chemie**: in Austria (and in the south of Germany – especially Bavaria) it is pronounced like *Kemie* and in the north of Germany more than *Schemie*...

Comment: The `ch` in *Mädchen* is the same as in *ich*.

Comment: *a (weak) /ch/ sound* – are you sure you want to write this with phonetic brackets? This seems unpronounceable to me and is very far from actual German pronunciation.

Comment: (not native speaker) I think "ch" in "nach" is strong, while in "Woche" is it weak. I don't know why, actually I couldn't say "Woche" with strong "ch" (if I would try, I would say "Woke" instead). Afaik, "Charlie" is said like in English. Mädchen is tricky, because this "dch" makes its pronouncation highly uncommon, if your first language doesn't have this sound you probably can't easily learn it (but Germans will understand you if you say Mächen or Mäd - chen).

Comment: Remember that German also has a large number of foreign loanwords whose spellings were never adjusted and wherein the *ch* is pronounced as it would be in the original language: *Chile* and *Check* (in hockey) would be like the English *ch,* *Chef* uses the French version like English *sh* and most decendents from Greek are pronounced with a *k* in the South or like your ‘weak’ version in the North: *Chemie, Chelat, Chirurg, China* (yes, that’s a Greek loan), …

Answer (score 6):

There are only the two *ch* sounds that you differentiate in the beginning, those in *ach* and *ich*. Now pronunciation of a sound is always influenced by surrounding sounds, often in ways that speakers are not aware of, because their language does not differentiate between these versions. As I am not an expert, I will not try to work this out in detail, but let me comment on your examples:

- *Nächste* can be pronounced with an *ich*-sound, and I do this at least when I enunciate carefully. However, if you try it you may agree that this is not easy to pronounce and that *näkste* is much easier, which is indeed how it is often pronounced, be it sloppiness or a regional variant.
- To me, one property of the English *ch* is that it starts with a *t*, so you may be just hearing the *d* (pronounced as *t*) in Mädchen. Otherwise the *ch* is pronounce just as in *ich*, except that it may be slightly more to the front of the mouth because of the surrounding *t* and *e*.
- Indeed the standard pronunciation of *-ig* as in *König* is *-ich*, but there is also the *-ik* variant. (Note that *Könige* has a *g* and *königlich* a *k*.) Standard pronunciation is a bit inconsistent here, as *-ich* is a originally a Northern variant, and the standard pronunciation does not follow other similar Northern features. Many speakers are not aware which variant is considered standard (and some may not even be sure how they usually pronounce it when you ask them) and some speakers from Northern Germany will overcompensate to *-ik* when trying to speak proper standard German.

Comment: The ‘overcompensation’ sounds more correct to me ;)

Comment: Please also note the special behaviour of _chs_ within the same syllable being pronounced as /ks/ as in _Fuchs_, _Achse_, but not _Schlauch-stück_.

Comment: This is why _Nächste_ is pronounced as it is. Pronouncing _Nächste_ as /nech-ste/ seems to be more of a regional dialect, especially since you otherwise would have to pronounce the _st_ as /scht/. (Except in northern German dialects where the st -> /scht/, sp -> /schp/ rules usually do not apply.)

Comment: @fer-rum, dem kann ich nicht folgen. Schreibe doch eine Antwort, wenn Du meinst, dass ich falsch liege.

Comment: Ich meine nicht, dass du generell falsch liegst, habe aber dennoch mal eine Antwort verfasst auf dass sie die bisherigen Erkenntnisse subsummieren möge :)

Comment: The `ch`in `Nächste` my also be pronouced as `h`.

Answer (score 2):

As usual in German, There are a few guidelines and then dialects come along and break everything apart.

**Basic rules:** There is

1. A "hard" *ch* spoken after the vowels a, o, u (also after au) like in *auch*, *Loch*
2. A "soft" *ch* spoken after the vowel e, i (also after ei), ä, ö, ü like in *reich*, *Bäche*, *Bücher*, *Löcher*
3. A /ks/ sound, when a *chs* is written within the same syllable as in *Fuchs*, but not *Buch|stabe*
4. If there is no preceding vowel in the same syllable, usually the following vowel in the same syllable is used (e.g. in the -chen ending)

**Advanced rules:** Depending on the words origin, pronunciation may vary heavily across dialects:

- The *ch* in *Nächste* developed from a hardening of the *h* in *nah*. So it is possible speak a /ks/ after rule 3), a soft *ch* after rule 2) (preceding *ä*), a hard *ch* after rule 1) since the *ä* is a shift of the *a* from *nah* or even nothing at all since the original *h* in *nah* is soundless as well. All these variations are done and it is dependent on the dialect what actually is chosen. In the standard speaking, the soundless and soft *ch* variation seem more prevalent.
- Words like *Chor*, *Chlor*, *Charakter* or *Chemie* derive from greek words written with the letter *Chi*, which is usually pronounced as /k/ (compare: english *chemistry*). However over time rule 4) took over, thus pronouncing *Chemie* with a soft *ch*. One might also cite the Arabic roots of the word for a hard *ch* sound or even the old Egyptian roots which again used a /k/ sound.
- Another shift is to turn a soft *ch* into a /sch/ sound, like in /nüscht/, /nischts/ (*nichts*). This is usually *perceived* as inferior pronunciation used by less educated people. (Although it might also be caused by a dialect.)

**Related sounds:** Pronouncing the -ig ending as /-ich/ or /-k/ are dialect variations that usually shift the pronunciation to be easier for the speaker. It is possible to speak these with a proper /-ig/ sound, but it also is terribly hard.

**Conclusion:** Use the basic rules when in doubt. Some words tend to have exceptions due to their historical development. Look up their etymology when in doubt, you will have to learn these. Dialects apply own rules.

Comment: From your comment I was not sure if it would, but this actually makes sense to me ;)

Comment: Uuuh. Bisher hab ich mich ja immer auf »Wer *Schemie* sagt, muss auch *Schlor* sagen«, beschränkt, aber ich finde »Wer *Schemie* sagt, muss auch *Schor/Scharakter* sagen«, fast noch besser =D

Answer (score 1):

Well, one rule is that the "strong" `ch` is normally only used after dark vowels, like *Dach*, *doch*, *Fach*, *Fuchur*. Otherwise you use the "light" `ch`, as in *Kirche*, *Seuche*, *Früchte*.

Exception: In Bavaria and possibly other southern dialects, the "strong" `ch` is sometimes also used where others use the "light" variant. Probably because "r" tends to turn into an "a" there sometimes, as in "Kiache" (*Kirche*).

*Mädchen* is never pronounced like *Charlie*, but always like *ich* (which is true for all *-chen* endings).

`-ig` is indeed sometimes (regionally different) pronounced like `-ich`.

There are some dialects that pronounce some words with a `sch` instead of a `ch` - in my opinion that is a terrible thing, but you will hear things like "Schemie" (*Chemie*) or "Schina" (*China*) often in certain regions. Nobody has so far been able to explain to me why you would say "Schina", but not "Schor" (*Chor*) or "Scharakter" (*Charakter*)... Maybe that also some dark/light vowel thing?

Comment: Naja, wenn ich mit »Wer *Schemie* sagt, muss auch *Schlor* sagen«, komme, habe ich schon ein paar Mal die Antwort »Und warum sagst du nicht *Kef?«,* gehört; andere bringen dann *Kile* (das Land in Südamerika) in die Diskussion ein. Man sollte die verschiedenen Ursprungssprachen noch im Hinterkopf behalten ;)

Comment: Weil das alles keine deutschen Worte sind. Und es heißt eben weder Kile noch Schile...

Answer (score -3):

> Strong (like in Hebrew), as in "nach" or "woche"

**correct**

> Weak, as in "Ich"

**correct**

> /x/ or /k/ as in nächste

**standard german: like ich**

> (This one got me really confused) Mädchen, as in the English word "Charlie"(?) at least when spoken at normal speed.

**standard german: like ich**

> This one is not a "ch" but definitely a (week) /ch/ sound - almost any of "--g" ending, as in "Vierzig"

**normally you speek an --g, but some German speak a --ch, the really right method is to speak an --g**

Comment: Regional pronounciation of *nächste* is indeed sometimes /k/ or even /g/. So it may not be Standard German, but it's not "false" or "wrong".

Comment: Some german regions don't follow the rules of german language. Bit it is Not right. Maybe i should use a better Word than false. But from the rules site it is false. But i will change it :)      by the way,  in you want to learn german, you always have to learn standard german. No matter where you learn it.

Comment: Basically everyone here pronounces it as /k/ or /g/, I can't even remember when I've heard last someone using /ç/. If you insist that this is "false", I suggest you come here and tell everyone...

Comment: @dirkt i know what you mean. But everyone have to learn standard german rules. 
I had editet my comment to be more lovely to you ;)

Please don´t discuss the rightness of standard german and reginal influence german. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: I guess the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vierzig) is not really right then.

Comment: @FrankAus5419135 "If you want to learn German, you always have to learn standard German. No matter where you learn it." Usually yes, and that is in many cases a particularly silly thing to do. I know many foreigners attending German classes in Switzerland and if they learn standard High German, which is usually the case, they have absolutely no use of their learned knowledge in everyday life, since the locally spoken and the language they learn in their courses are not mutually intelligble.

Comment: @jarnbo maybe. But i didn't want to rate the sense in this. I only wrote the facts :)

Comment: @Carsten S..  I dort think you Art right. The Duden is part of some who decides the rules...